# Wrong position and radius on update pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm having some problems while updating a pack layout that is composed by a `circle` inside a `g` element, where the translation is controled by `g` and the radius is controled by the `circle`:

```
<g transform="translate(1,1)"><circle r="1"></circle></g>
```

The update was possible with the translation controlled by the circle, but I'm having the wrong `x`, `y` and `r` with a `g` as a container, as in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/h5ocm18s/).

```
var diameter = 300;

function translate(x, y) {
  return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}

// The layout I'm using now
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
  .value(function(d) { return 1; });

// The basic container
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");

// My initial data source
var data = {
  name: "Languages",
  children: [{
    name: "Functional",
    children: [
      { name: "OCaml" },
      { name: "Haskell" },
      { name: "Erlang" }
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Imperative",
    children: [
      { name: "BASIC" },
      { name: "Clipper" }
    ]
  }]
};

(window.update = function() {
  // Modify the current data object
  data.children.push({
    name: "NEW ELEMENT " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  });

  // Select *ALL* elements
  var selection = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes);

  // Select *ONLY NEW* nodes and work on them
  selection
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", "black");

  // Recompute *ALL* elements
  // Here the results aren't consistent, I always get the wrong translation
  // and radius, therefore, the elements are badly positioned
  selection
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return translate(d.x, d.y);
    })
    .selectAll("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    });
})();

// Set the height
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

I see I'm selecting the correct elements, but why I'm having the wrong results whenever I call `update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code is mostly correct, but `selectAll("circle")` will select all the circle elements and apply the radius of the inner element for all of them. We need to select just the inner circle, therefore, `select("circle")` solves the question ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/h5ocm18s/1/)).

Comment: You can also specify a key function to `.data()` https://jsfiddle.net/h5ocm18s/2/